# How to display a two-dimensional string array properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So this is the table I am making

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string tables[5][14] = 
    { { "0", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30", "33", "36", "2 to 1" },
    { "2", "5", "8", "11", "14", "17", "20", "23", "26", "29", "32", "35", "2 to 1" },
    { "1", "4", "7", "10", "13", "16", "19", "22", "25", "28", "31", "34", "2 to 1" },
    { "1st 12", "2nd 12", "3rd 12" },
    { "1-10", "Even", "Red", "Black", "Odd", "19-36" } };

     cout << tables << endl;
    return 0;    
}
```

So I run this code and my compiler does not show any errors but all that is printed is a strange string of letters and numbers,

> 007EF610

I have never encountered this before and could really use some advice, thanks for your time!

Comment: That's not a weird string of letters/numbers, that's hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

Your code prints `tables`, which is the address of the first string. If you want to print all strings contained in your array of array of strings, you have to write a loop yourself that goes through all `tables[i][j]`, for instance:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
{
  for(int j=0; j<14; ++j)
  {
    cout << tables[i][j] << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 14

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string tables[ ROWS ][ COLS ] =
    {
        { "0", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30", "33", "36", "2 to 1" },
        { "2", "5", "8", "11", "14", "17", "20", "23", "26", "29", "32", "35", "2 to 1" },
        { "1", "4", "7", "10", "13", "16", "19", "22", "25", "28", "31", "34", "2 to 1" },
        { "1st 12", "2nd 12", "3rd 12", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
        { "1-10", "Even", "Red", "Black", "Odd", "19-36", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" }
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ )
        {
            cout << tables[ i ][ j ] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    system( "pause" );

    return 0;    
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 2 to 1 
2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 2 to 1  
1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 2 to 1  
1st 12 2nd 12 3rd 12
```

**What is happening on you code is:**
You assumed that `cout << tables << endl` is able to print the whole table. But this is not true. `cout` can not automatically have any information about your table. So you must loop over it correctly.

The number you were getting (like 007EF610) is in fact the address of the `tables` array in memory.

Answer (score 1):

First, properly initialize the array (you need to fill each entry [5][14]:

```
string tables[5][14] =
{
   { "0", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30", "33", "36", "2 to 1" },
   { "2", "5", "8", "11", "14", "17", "20", "23", "26", "29", "32", "35", "2 to 1", "" },
   { "1", "4", "7", "10", "13", "16", "19", "22", "25", "28", "31", "34", "2 to 1", "" },
   { "1st 12", "2nd 12", "3rd 12", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
   { "1-10", "Even", "Red", "Black", "Odd", "19-36", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" }
};
```

Then loop through it, skip the empty values:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<14;j++){
        if (!tables[i][j].empty()) {
            cout << tables[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 2 to 1 
2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 2 to 1 
1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 2 to 1 
1st 12 2nd 12 3rd 12 
1-10 Even Red Black Odd 19-36
```

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string tables[5][14] =
    {
       { "0", "3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30", "33", "36", "2 to 1" },
       { "2", "5", "8", "11", "14", "17", "20", "23", "26", "29", "32", "35", "2 to 1", "" },
       { "1", "4", "7", "10", "13", "16", "19", "22", "25", "28", "31", "34", "2 to 1", "" },
       { "1st 12", "2nd 12", "3rd 12", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
       { "1-10", "Even", "Red", "Black", "Odd", "19-36", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" }
    };
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<14;j++){
            if (!tables[i][j].empty()) {
                cout << tables[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You know, in `C` and `C++`, simply printing the name of the variable won't print it's contents, if it's anything other than the simpler data types, ie, `int`,`float`,`long`,`string`,`char` etc..

the variable `tables` is, as you said, a 2D array. To print its contents, you need to loop over each element in the array and print that:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<14; j++){
        cout<<tables[i][j]<<'\t';
      }
      cout<<endl;
}
```

PS: what you're getting as the output - `007EF610` - is the base address of the 2D array, ie, the location in memory where it is stored.

Answer (score 0):

First understand what does it mean this declaration

```
string tables[5][14]
```

It means table is an 2d array(which has 5 rows and 14 columns) of string object

It would help you to understand the mistake you have done